# Globally declare UIColor in project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uicolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C defining UIColor constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824187/objective-c-defining-uicolor-constants)

I'd like to use few colours throughout my app. Instead of creating a UIColor at every instance or in every viewController is there a way by which i can use it throughout the app.

or is it wise to use a ColourConstants.h header file where i #define each colour i want to use

i.e

```
#define SCARLET [UIColor colorWithRed:207.0/255.0 green:47.0/255.0 blue:40.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would use a category on UIColor. For example:

```
// In UIColor+ScarletColor.h

@interface UIColor (ScarletColor)

+ (UIColor*)scarletColor;

@end


// In UIColor+ScarletColor.m

@implementation UIColor (ScarletColor)

+ (UIColor*)scarletColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:207.0/255.0 green:47.0/255.0 blue:40.0/255.0 alpha:1];
}

@end
```

And when you want to use the color you only have to do this:

```
#import "UIColor+ScarletColor.h"

....

UIColor *scarlet = [UIColor scarletColor];
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: +1
very straightforward and simple. should have thought of it :-)

Comment: Tip: Place the `#import "UIColor+ScarletColor.h"` in your `Prefix.pch` file and you can access it anywhere. Without importing explicitly

Answer (score 2):

A macro is more convenient, as it's defined only in one place.

But it will still create a new instance, every time it's used, as a macro is just text replacement for the pre-processor.

If you want to have a unique instance, you'll have to use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` (which means `extern`).

In a public .h file, declares the following:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT UIColor * scarlet;
```

This will tell the compiler that the `scarlet` variable (of type `UIColor`) will exist at some point (when the program is linked).
So it will allow you to use it.

Then you need to create that variable, in a .m file.
You can't assign its value directly, as it's a runtime value, so just set it to nil:

```
UIColor * scarlet = nil;
```

And then, at some point in your program (maybe in your app's delegate), set its value:

```
scarlet = [ [ UIColor ... ] retain ];
```

Do not forget to retain it, as it's a global variable which needs to live during the entire life-time of the program.

This way, you have only one instance, accessible from everywhere.